# z alpha by 2 distribution-help!

Tags: statistical-inference

How do we use z aplha by 2 distribution? I don't get it one bit. For the table it says z on lhs and second decimal place of z on the top in the rhs. Firstly if e.g apha is 0.05 then apha by 2 is 0.025 so we know that we have z subscript 0.025  so how on earth do we use the table if we know only the value of alpha and not the value of z, what on earth do we look for in the tables?

s[image]

Answer (score 0):

if $\alpha=0.05$, that means you are looking for $P(Z \leq z)=1-0.05=0.95$

You look where in the table (more or less) 0.95 ist written. Then you look on the lhs, take the value and add the value on the top of the column.

Was this your question ?

greetings,

calculus.